# Is there a way to three formControlName that share the same property name in a Angular Reactive Form?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I've created a reactive form based on the data I receive from a REST API and also static content. Once the user submits the form the data is sent.  I have one section where the property name of a formControl is the same name.  e.g.

```
   <ng-container formArrayName="documentFields">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let doc of documentFields(comIndex).controls; let skillIndex=index">
      <ng-container [formGroupName]="skillIndex">
        <div class="row mb-3">
          <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Category:</label>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <ng-container>
              <select id="" class="form-select"  formControlName="value">
                <option  selected>Select</option>
                <option *ngFor="let c of taxonomyResponse.categoryList">{{c.name}}</option>
              </select>
            </ng-container>
          </div>
          <label class="col-auto col-form-label">Sub-Category:</label>
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value">
              <option selected>Select</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>
```

As you can see "value" is called twice.  In order for the POST request to work these property filed need to be the same.  Here is my method.

```
newDocumentFields() {
  return this.fb.group({
      name: '',
      value: '',
    })
}
```

And this is how the response should look when sending the POST

```
 "documents": [
  {
    "name": "1.pdf",
    "documentId": 34,
    "documentFields": [
      {
        "name": "",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "",
        "value": ""
      }
    ]
]
```

The "value"  will have data from a service call but the "name" will be static.

Comment: Would be great if you can further explain for the `documentFields` array structure. So, in every category, the user can select a category and sub-category, how about if the user selects more than 1 category?  The `documentFields` array will contain 4,6,8... objects?

Comment: @YongShun the documents array is the main array with the documentFields as the inner array with three objects.  The user has the ability to upload a new document.  Here are names:


 "documents": [
  {
    "name": "1.pdf",
    "documentId": 34,
    "documentFields": [
      {
        "name": "documentCategory",
        "value": ""
      },
      {
        "name": "documentSubCategory",
        "value": ""
      }
    ]
]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically within a `FormGroup`/`object`, you can't have multiple keys with the same name.

Based on your expected result, within the `documentFields` array, it will have 2 `FormGroup`/`object`(s), the first one will be Category and followed by the Sub-Category.

You are required to use 2 FormGroups instead of a single `FormGroup`.

Your `documentFields` FormArray structure should be as below:

```
<ng-container formArrayName="documentFields">
  <ng-container
    *ngFor="let skillIndex of documentFieldsIndexes(comIndex);"
  >
    <div class="row mb-3">
      <label class="col-sm-1 col-form-label">Category:</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="skillIndex">
          <select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value">
            <option selected>Select</option>
            <option *ngFor="let c of taxonomyResponse.categoryList">
              {{c.name}}
            </option>
          </select>
        </ng-container>
      </div>

      <label class="col-auto col-form-label">Sub-Category:</label>
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <ng-container [formGroupName]="skillIndex + 1">
          <select id="" class="form-select" formControlName="value">
            <option selected>Select</option>
          </select>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
</ng-container>
```

For the iteration (`*ngFor`) part, you need to iterate every 2 elements in order to make each iteration will have 2 elements. Thus, there is why the below function is needed with:

1. Divide the total number of elements within the `documentFields` array by 2.
2. Construct an array for the index to be iterated in `*ngFor`, the values (indexes) will be started from 0 and incremented by 2. Example: 0, 2, 4...

```
documentFieldsIndexes(comIndex: number) {
  return Array(this.documentFields(comIndex).controls.length / 2)
    .fill(0)
    .map((x, i) => i * 2);
}
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-e48hbt?file=src%2Fmain.html)

Comment: thanks @YongShun.  It's working in your demo but when I try to add to existing code I'm getting two undefined errors (reading 'controls') and (reading 'push')

Comment: Can you share your code in StackBlitz?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xpna4p?file=src%2Fmain.html. I added my documentForm property and the html code that goes with it.

Comment: Sorry about that.  I added my code but still am getting an error. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-xpna4p?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: The problem is due to `documents` getter. Please check Line 97 and I drop the remark. [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-1rf89d?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

Comment: thank you!! Now i just need to be able to add and remove the documents Array.  Here is a link to my code on line 104.

Comment: forgot to add link, @YongShun https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vte8xw?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: I'm trying to add and remove the documents array now but only the file field is duplicating.  I've updated the stack blitz link, https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vte8xw?file=src%2Fmain.ts @YongShun

Answer (score 0):

Basically in angular a formControlName should be unique. It would also be a good idea to implement a smart/dummy principle where you have one component making the actual endpoint calls (dummy component) that calls the smart component (your form/formarray) and passes in the required objects with the @Input() decorator. Then when form changes, emit the form (or as a simplified object) with the @Output() decorator. If you need the fields to have the same value, you can either set it with form.get('formControlName').patchValue('valueFromOtherField') or map it before emitting it to the dummy component. Then in the dummy component you just call a method bound to the output of the smart component. In this method you can just map or set the value for the endpoint call.

I hope you get the idea. It is just a suggestion to use this smart/dummy component Principe as is has many advantages, such as better readability and easier testing possibilities. It is also good to always use the singe responsibility principle.